# Django ViewDoesNotExist error on deployment only

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django app that I thought was nearly ready to deploy. Everything works on the development server, but when hosted on a test Apache/mod_wsgi server, I get an error for every last one of my views.

If I put in a invalid URL, it serves me the list of valid URL's as expected, but nothing else seems to work as per the development server.

I have tried accessing from other PC's on the local network to no joy.

If anyone can shed any light on the issue it would be appreciated. A good couple of hours reading around hasn't helped so far.

The errors are as follows;

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.1.4/results.php
Django Version: 1.2.4
Python Version: 2.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'results',
 'django.contrib.admin']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  80.                     response = middleware_method(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/middleware/common.py" in process_request
  57.             if (not _is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/middleware/common.py" in _is_valid_path
  143.         urlresolvers.resolve(path, urlconf)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  302.     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  217.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  217.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  123.             return self.callback, args, kwargs
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_callback
  135.             raise ViewDoesNotExist("Tried %s in module %s. Error was: %s" % (func_name, mod_name, str(e)))

Exception Type: ViewDoesNotExist at /results.php
Exception Value: Tried index in module results.views. Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'cbook'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your `results.views` file, that breaks everything!

Apparently the `Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'cbook'`. So search through your `results.views` python file for "cbook" you may be trying to import cbook or using it somewhere. Either way the problem will be "cbook" related.

Comment: I don't suppose you could suggest the type of error that I'd be looking for? I've had a good look though, but can't see anything. All brackets closed, definitions finished, indenting as required e.t.c. Thanks for the responce.

Comment: Marcus, Interestingly, it would appear it was down to an Apache misconfiguration. Re-installing Apache seemed to fix the issue. Thank you for your input with this issue however.